# Unexplainable behavior with PySpark and dropping nulls

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark DataFrame in PySpark that I am trying to remove the nulls from.

Before, when cleaning things up during parsing, I ran a `convert_to_null` method on the `title` column that basically checks whether a string literally says `"None"` and if so, converts that to an actual `None`. That way, Spark converts it to an internal null type.

Now, I'm trying to drop the rows with that null type in the `title` column. Here is everything I've tried to remove my nulls:

`new_df = df.na.drop('title')`

`new_df = df[F.col('title').isNotNull()]`

`new_df = df[~F.col('title').isNull()]`

But I always get this error at the `new_df.show()` call a few lines after:

> `Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o2022.showString.
>   : org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 87.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.0 in stage 87.0 (TID 314, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 230, in main
>       process()
>     File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 225, in process
>       serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
>     File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 324, in dump_stream
>       self.serializer.dump_stream(self._batched(iterator), stream)
>     File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 139, in dump_stream
>       for obj in iterator:
>     File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 313, in _batched
>       for item in iterator:
>     File "<string>", line 1, in <lambda>
>     File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 75, in <lambda>
>       return lambda *a: f(*a)
>     File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/util.py", line 55, in wrapper
>       return f(*args, **kwargs)
>     File "<ipython-input-16-48bc3ec1b5d9>", line 5, in replace_none_with_null`
>   
>   **`TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not NoneType`**

I think I'm going crazy. I have no clue how to fix things. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Your code fail in Python code (like. `RDD` or `udf`), not here. Please post a [mcve] ([How to make good reproducible Apache Spark Dataframe examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48427185/6910411))